# Add custom image to Action in RCP application

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, icons, swt, eclipse-rcp

I've created a custom view in my Eclipse applicatuion using [this](https://eclipse.org/articles/viewArticle/ViewArticle2.html) tutorial. I also added some custom `Action`s and I would like to assign custom icons to them. I tried to use `setImageDescriptor()` (as you can see in the following code) but unfortunately I only see the text in my bar, but no icons.

```
private void createActions() {
    Action myAction = new Action("My Action") {
        public void run() {
            // do something
        }
    };
    myAction.setImageDescriptor(Activator.getImageDescriptor("icons/my_action.gif"));
}
```

The `Acrivator` class looks like this:

```
public class Activator extends AbstractUIPlugin {

    // The plug-in ID
    public static final String PLUGIN_ID = "my.product.plugin"; //$NON-NLS-1$

    // standard stuff...

    public static ImageDescriptor getImageDescriptor(String path) {
        return imageDescriptorFromPlugin(PLUGIN_ID, path);
    }
}
```

Can someone help?

**Solution:** The plugin id was not correct, although it was generated automatically. After changing it, the icons are set correctly.

Comment: `Activator.getImageDescriptor` is probably returning `null`. Show us that code.

Comment: So have you checked if getImageDescriptor is returning null? Is the plugin id correct? Is the image path correct?

Comment: In fact, the plugin id was not correct. I should have checked it. Thank you very much!